# WPF Styles - Please help me understand why this works the way it does

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyle">
    <Setter Property="Window.Background" Value="Orange"/>
</Style>

<Button Content="Ok" Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}"/>
```

Why does the button actually get an orange background, if the setter is specified as Window.Background?

This does **not** give the TextBlock an orange background:

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}"/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither `Button` nor `Window` actually define the `Background` property, they both inherit it from `Control`.

So even though you wrote `Window.Background`, the setter is actually bound to the property by using the `Control.BackgroundProperty` field which also applied to `Button`.

Comment: Thanks Sven! But how come <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}"/> does not make the TextBlock's Background orange? TextBlock also inherits from Control...

Comment: @Gustavo, [TextBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.aspx) directly inherits from `FrameworkElement`, not from `Control`.

Comment: Indeed, TextBlock doesn't inherit from Control, and defines its own Background property, so the only way to set the background of a TextBlock is to use a Setter on TextBlock.Background directly.

Answer (score 2):

It works because the `Background` property is attached to [Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.aspx) class which both `Window` and `Button` have as ancestor